# Does dropbox change linebreaks in files?

Tags: dropbox, linebreaks

when i save a file to my Dropbox at home on my PC is seems to have '\n' line breaks, but when i open the file on my Mac at work the line breaks have mutated to '\r\n' windows line breaks.

could dropbox be doing this? or do i need to look elsewhere for the source of my problem?

Comment: How do you check it? Which apps do you use to write / read the file? Please be more specific!

Comment: What text editor are you using on both systems?

Answer (score 12):

Either the program on your PC changed them or more than likely, the program you opened the file in your Mac changed them.

Dropbox itself is file content agnostic.

Comment: Yeah, Dropbox just saves it as a bytestream and does not care about what is inside.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox shouldn't - though it might be the text editor doing it - i've seen this happen working between windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers here allude, it's not a Dropbox issue. This is a common thing when moving between operating systems/file systems. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems for example. Many text editors can toggle between the two; this is part of the Preferences dialog from [EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/), for example

[image: EditPlus gives the user a choice of how to save files, which newline character(s) to use]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a dropbox editor issue. Dropbox changes LFs into CRs when the text file that is saved is not ANSI but a UTF variant. Many android editors behave this way. QuickEdit by Rhythm worked for me in the end. I can now interchangeably use text files between quickedit on android and notepad in windows.